Setting Categories Automatically for a Shared Inbox in Outlook
I'm trying to add a category to any incoming mail that has a specific string in the subject. The strings are in a text file that gets exported from a local database daily. I've gotten this to work in my primary inbox, but I need it to work in a shared inbox instead (though I don't mind if it works on every inbox).
Here's the code I've got so far, stuck into ThisOutlookSession:
Private WithEvents Items As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set Items = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    If TypeOf item Is MailItem Then
        AutoCategorize item
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub AutoCategorize(olItem As MailItem)
    Dim FSO As Object, MyFile As Object
    Dim FileName As String, SubList As Variant

    Dim i As Long

    FileName = "S:\Output.txt"
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set MyFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1)
    SubList = Split(MyFile.ReadAll, vbNewLine)

    For i = LBound(SubList) To UBound(SubList) - 1
        If InStr(olItem.Subject, " " & SubList(i) & " ") Then
            olItem.Categories = olItem.Categories & "; " & "MyCategory"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    olItem.Save

End Sub

EDIT: Got it working! Here's the revised block, shamelessly stolen from https://www.slipstick.com/developer/working-vba-nondefault-outlook-folders/
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim NS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient
    
    Set NS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objOwner = NS.CreateRecipient("sharedemail")
        objOwner.Resolve
    
    If objOwner.Resolve Then
        Set Items = NS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox).Items
    End If
End Sub


move "olItem.Save" before "Exit For"

Replace Session.GetDefaultFolder with Session.CreateRecipient/ Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder.
